# Regex (Java): How do I replace "||" with "| |" repeatedly

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string of pipe-delimited data:

```
123456|abcd|||65464|hgfhgf
```

How can I replace any occurrance of `||` with: `| |`?

So it would end up looking like this:

```
123456|abcd| | |65464|hgfhgf
```

I tried using the simple Java expression:

```
delimString.replaceAll("\\\|\\\|", "| |");
```

but that only replaced the first occurrence:

```
123456|abcd| ||65464|hgfhgf
```

So I need something to make it repeat (greedily I think).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\|(?=\\|)", "| ");
```

The regex explained without Java's double backslashes:

```
\|   # Match a literal |
(?=  # only if it's followed by
 \|  # another literal |.
)    # End of lookahead assertion
```

You could even *go wild* and replace the *empty space* between two pipes with a space character:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?<=\\|)(?=\\|)", " ");
```

Comment: Excellent. Regex often has me stumped, but your explanation makes things understandable.
Thank you.

Comment: Very accurate regex and well explained also +1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here that the match position is already past the 2nd | you replaced, so it does not count.
You'll have to use a while loop to do this.

Comment: The diagnosis is correct, the solution is overkill ;-) See Tims answer.

Comment: Well, this is indeed quite elegant (for regex literates, that is:), but I find "overkill" a bit stark a word for a nicely readable while loop ...

Comment: Agreed. Overkill is too strong a word. "unnecessary" would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551044/regex-java-how-do-i-replace-with-repeatedly/5551110#5551110) - a loop solution is more lines of code but easier to understand (at least it doesn't have to be explained ;) ):

```
String test = "abc|def||ghi|||jkl";

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
char previous = 0;
for (char c:test.toCharArray()) {
  if (c == '|' && previous == '|')
    result.append(" ");
  result.append(c);
  previous = c;
}

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This is a nice loop and more understandable than the regex.  Minor gripe:  `result.append(' ');` would be _slightly_ faster.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about my answer before i made a mistake. I just updated.

This is an alternative that will work 100% sure have a look at it:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {

        String data = "123456|abcd|||65464|hgfhgf";
        String modified = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length();i++) {
            if(data.charAt(i) == '|') {
                modified += "| |";
            }
            else {
                modified += "" + data.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(modified);
}
```

At the end it will look like this:

> 123456| |abcd| || || |65464| |hgfhgf

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels...did you test this? The output is `| |1| |2| |3| |4| |5| |6| ||| |a| |b| |c| |d| ||| ||| ||| |6| |5| |4| |6| |4| ||| |h| |g| |f| |h| |g| |f| |`

Comment: this won't work like author wants.
this will change | to | | after 123456

Comment: @ sfrj, and again: Author wants result to be `123456|abcd| | |65464|hgfhgf` Compare with your result.

Comment: Sorry about that, i just updated it, have a look it works now.

Comment: At least sfrj is trying, a sincere effort does not deserve a downvote imho. @srfj: you need to make sure the *next* character is also a | before you append "| |". And appending the second | is wrong, you should append only |. Actually it may be better if you check the *previous* character, not next. Think about why.

Comment: @sfrj: This is still not doing what the OP wanted. You're replacing every single pipe. Chris only wants to *insert* spaces between pipes if there are two or more in a row. And, for the record, it's not my downvote. But your solution is completely wrong.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Sorry I failed, this answer is not good. Tim's answer is definitely correct and better solution.